# Are required fields added by default to a new page layout?

Tags: page-layout, fields

Are all required fields added by default to a new page layout or does it add only a certain set of fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is required at field level or it is a Master-detail lookup then it is automatically added to the layout and you wont be able to remove it.